# Como resolver pull request com branch deletado (unknown repository)?

Tags: git, github

Apos ser feito um `pull request` foi removido o branch vinculado e a mensagem `unknown repository` é apresentada.

Existe alguma forma de re-vincular este `pull request` a um novo branch ou a única maneira é refazer o `pull request`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Está é uma questão, amplamente discutida, [nesta issue no GitHub](https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/168).

Não existe uma alternativa para resolver está questão. O importante é não deletar o `branch` enquanto o `pull request` não seja aprovado.